# how to make a gradient color and set it on ImageView (android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-imageview

gradient.xml:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:endColor="#aaFFB5B9"
    android:startColor="#aaFFDEB5"
     />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />
<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp"/>
```

gradient2.xml:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:startColor="#aaECB4FF"
    android:endColor="#aaB4CCFF"
     />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />

<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp"/>
```

ImageView:
android:foreground="@drawable/gradient"

ImageView2:
android:foreground="@drawable/gradient2"

Comment: You want `android:src` (or `app:srcCompat`) if you're setting the source for an `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

In your drawable/gradient.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--You have to specify the shape of the gradient-->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:endColor="#aaFFB5B9"
        android:startColor="#aaFFDEB5"
        />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

In your Imageview:

```
        <ImageView
         ...
            android:src="@drawable/gradient"
            />
```

Do the same with ImageView2